# Exp:resso Store Send Order Emails To Different Email Addresses

Tags: expresso-store, expresso, extension

Is it possible to supply dynamic BCC's on Exp:resso store order confirmation emails?

I have an ecommerce site that tutors can list courses on, and students can buy courses. When a course is purchased the student gets an email, but I need to notify the tutor too (which is an EE member).

I have got as far as writing an extension that taps into **store_order_complete_end**, which means I have access to the **Store\Model\Order** and **Store\Model\Email** objects... but I'm not sure what to do from there. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Oh it appears it is very straightforward. So in the extension grab the store emails (I'm just getting all for development) then you can set the BCC attribute as per below.

```
$emails = Store\Model\Email::whereIn('id', [1])->where('enabled', 1)->get();
foreach ($emails as $email) {
    # For my IDE
    $email instanceof Store\Model\Email;
    $email->setAttribute("bcc", "myaddress@mydomain.com");
    $sent = ee()->store->email->send($email, $order);
}
```